# Repository: Examples for a Decorator / Repository pattern in C#

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, entity-framework-4.1, repository-pattern, decorator

I had the wrong idea of how to create a repository.  I created a single repository for each Entity that would CRUD using an ORM, which worked very well.  However, I needed more and didn't know how to do it without messing up my existing code.

I wanted to add filtering based on Logins.  I eventually found Castle.Windsor references showing something like this:

```
var ControllerContactRepo = new SecurityContactRepo( new ContactRepo() );
```

Where the Controller in MVC accesses one repository for Contacts which handles both CRUD and security without the controller knowing it.  I presume the POCOs passed between repositories change based on the Liskov substitution principle, and the repositories are done with the decorator design pattern?

**Where can I see some C# examples of this technique before I jump head first in to Castle Windsor?**  I am familiar with Constructor based IoC but not so much DI.  I really want to know the nuts and bolts of this technique before I abstract it away with Windsor.

Links to website tutorials would be great, or book suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good article for you http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/